# How can I create an enumerator that does certain things after iteration?

Tags: ruby, block, enumerator

How can I create an enumerator that optionally takes a block? I want some method `foo` to be called with some arguments and an optional block. If it is called with a block, iteration should happen on the block, and something should be done on it, involving the arguments given. For example, if `foo` were to take a single array argument, apply `map` on it with the given block, and return the result of `join` applied to it, then it would look like:

```
foo([1, 2, 3]){|e| e * 3}
# => "369"
```

If it is called without a block, it should return an enumerator, on which instance methods of `Enumerator` (such as `with_index`) should be able to apply, and execute the block in the corresponding way:

```
enum = foo([1, 2, 3])
# => Enumerator
enum.with_index{|e, i| e * i}
# => "026"
```

I defined `foo` using a condition to see if a block is given. It is easy to implement the case where the block is given, but the part returning the enumerator is more difficult. I guess I need to implement a sublass `MyEnum` of `Enumerator` and make `foo` return an instance of it:

```
def foo a, &pr
  if pr
    a.map(&pr).join
  else
    MyEnum.new(a)
  end
end

class MyEnum < Enumerator
  def initialize a
    @a = a
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

But calling `MyEnum.new` raises a warning message: `Enumerator.new without a block is deprecated; use Object#to_enum`. If I use `to_enum`, I think it would return a plain `Enumerator` instance, not the `MyEnum` with the specific feature built in. On top of that, I am not sure how to implement `MyEnum` in the first place. How can I implement such enumerator? Or, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: `a` implements `map` and not `to_enum`?

Comment: It should apply `map` at different timings: immediately if a block is given. And if a block is not given, then it should apply it when things like `with_index` is called with a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
def foo a, &pr
  if pr
    a.map(&pr).join
  else
    o = Object.new
    o.instance_variable_set :@a, a
    def o.each *y
      foo @a.map { |z| yield z, *y } { |e| e }
    end
    o.to_enum
  end
end
```

Then we have

```
enum = foo([1,2,3])
enum.each { |x| 2 * x } # "246"
```

or

```
enum = foo([1,2,3])
enum.with_index { |x, i| x * i } # "026"
```

Inspiration was drawn from the [Enumerator documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html). Note that all of your expectations about enumerators like you asked for hold, because `.to_enum` takes care of all that. `enum` is now a legitimate `Enumerator`!

```
enum.class # Enumerator
```

Comment: That is cool. So your point seems to be to implement the "kernel/seed" of the enumerator (your `o`) which will act as expected when converted to an enumerator, instead of implementing an enumerator subclass. I could not think of that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it!